# Construction of an $N$ electron orbital and spin state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, symmetry, atomic-physics, representation-theory

Consider a system of $N$ electrons. Their Hilbert space is the antisymmetric subspace of $\mathcal H = \mathcal H_e^{\otimes N}$, where $\mathcal H_e \cong L^2(\mathbb R^3)\otimes \mathbb C^2$ is the single electron Hilbert space. Let's suppose that the hamiltonian doesn't couple the orbital and the spin degrees of freedom and is rotation invariant. I want to understand how to build the state $|L,S,J,M_j\rangle$ with the quantum numbers of orbital, spin and total angular momentum from the single electron states, like it is done in an atom. I would like to do this in terms of representation theory (with my probably naive understanding).

The example I have in mind is the He atom. There, we have a wavefunction which is factorized in an orbital and spin part. There being only two electrons, there is only one permutation. We have a representation of the permutation on $L^2(\mathbb R^6)$ (which exchanges positions), on $\mathbb C^4$ (which exchanges spins) and also on $\mathcal H = L^2(\mathbb R^6) \otimes \mathbb C^4$ (which exchanges both). The point is that I can decompose both the orbital and the spin Hibert space in permutation irreps, which for $N = 2$ are only the symmetric and antisymmetric part, and choosing e.g. a symmetric orbital part and an antisymmetric spin part I automatically get a globally antisymmetric state, i.e. belonging to a particular permutation irrep on $\mathcal H$. Also, to each permutation irrep on $\mathbb C^4$ there corresponds a fixed total spin eigenvalue, which in my understanding means that the permutation irreps are the same as the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ ones. This strikes me as important and interesting but I don't understand it.

I would like to understand how this generalizes to arbitrary $N$. I think this is relevant, for instance, when building the electron configuration of the oxygen $2p$ orbital: we have $4$ electrons with $l = 1$ but the total $L$ can at most be $2$. This is of course due to Pauli exclusion principle, but for a proper general understanding it seems like it is necessary to incorporate symmetry with respect to to permutations in the composition of angular momenta.

I know that the irreps of the $N$th order permutation group correspond to Young diagrams.

So the **first question** is: is it possible to choose  particular irreps of the permutation group on the orbital and spin Hilbert space, such that their (tensor) product gives the antisymmetric irrep on the total Hilbert space $\mathcal H$? If yes, is there a way to visualize this with Young diagrams?

The **second question** is: as I was wondering in the He example, how does such a construction relate to the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ representation theory? Do the permutation group irreps on the spin space correspond to $\hat s^2$ eigenspaces (spin operator), i.e. $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ irreps? If so, why?

The **third question** is: what about the application to the atomic orbitals?

Any reference suggestion is appreciated. I know that I made a few “conjectures” and assumptions which might be wrong, so please correct me wherever necessary.

Comment: AFAIK and see in the definition of orbital, a single electron occupies and orbital. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital  . are you talking of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_hybridisation ? it would not apply to simple atoms.

Comment: @anna v Sorry, I'm not talking about molecules, but about a single many-electron atom. What do you mean with “it would not apply to single atoms”? Of course, in the central field approximation, atoms do have hydrogen-like orbitals...

Comment: It is many orbitals that exist for atoms, if you read the links . one for each energy level of the solution for that atom. they cannot be bunched into a collective orbital within main stream physics, which is what is being discussed on this site.

Comment: @annav Sorry, but I can't understand how I'm bunching many orbitals together. Are you maybe talking about the “global wavefunction”?

Comment: Possibly I do not understand what your are attempting. Lets see if you get any answers .